# how to pass values from activity one to activity two without losing value?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

hello im android developer and im using kotlin language im trying to make xo game i have 2 problems

- first problem : i want to pass data from first activity to second one i already did it but the problem is when i go from activity 2 to 3 and back from 3 to 2 it gives me null values why? and how can i fix this
- second problem : when i go from activity 1 to activity 2 and back to activity 1 with back button i want to refresh activity 1 and reset everything how can i do this ?

i'm using intent like this but i want to save values without getting null values !

```
  - activity one : 
        fun startgame(view: View) {
                val editone = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.playerone)
                val playerone = editone.text.toString()
                val edittwo = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.playertwo)
                val playertwo = edittwo.text.toString()
                val intent = Intent(this,TwoPlayers::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("firstplayername",playerone)
                intent.putExtra("secondplayername",playertwo)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
    - activity 2 :
            override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                    setContentView(R.layout.players_two)
            
                    val xwinstxt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.xwinstxt)
                    val owinstxt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.owinstxt)
            
                    val Intent = intent
            
                    val extraOne:String = Intent.getStringExtra("firstplayername").toString()
                    val extraTwo:String = Intent.getStringExtra("secondplayername").toString()
                    xwinstxt.text = extraOne
                    owinstxt.text = extraTwo
            
                }
```

Comment: When going from Activity 2 to Activity 3 and then going back to Activity 2, the onCreate method of Activity 2 does not get called. To understand the Activity lifecycle in detail, refer to the official Android documentation here.

Comment: Perhaps this should be a single activity, using two fragments or composables for individual screens.

Comment: how can i use fragments to show winner result ?

Comment: You Can also use shared preference if you need to keep data thought the application lifecycle.